# How do I hide the mouse pointer on Windows 10?

Tags: mouse

How do I hide the mouse pointer on Windows 10? I'm using an Remote Desktop software, so I can already see my base machine's pointer, in addition to the pointer to the machine I'm RDP-ing to. Therefore, on the machine that I'm RDP-ing to, I would like to disable the mouse pointer completely so I do not see 2 mouse pointers. How do I achieve this?